# I just want to rotate and move the image!! (Javascript, <canvas>, html 5)

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

http://gist.github.com/232194

I know it's something wrong with my transformations in drawGuy. Can anyone help me figure out how to rotate just the image? Currently it rotates fine, but I something with the transforms is distorting it, so that it doesn't follow the mouse correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of translating forward and then translating backward again, simply push your current state onto the stack before you traslate/rotate, and when you're done - pop your state back off the stack.  This is how most graphical applications make use of translations/rotations.

Also, you're translating by `x, y`, then additionally calling `ctx.drawImage(guy, x, y)`.  This is going to, in effect, double the offset.  I'd either get rid of the translate call, or change the position arguments for the drawImage call to `0, 0`.

```
function drawGuy() {
    ctx.save();                                                                                                                        
    ctx.translate(x,y);     
    ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);                                                                               
    ctx.drawImage(guy, 0, 0); 
    ctx.restore();                                            
}
```

Check out the spec about `context.save()` and `context.restore()` (the way canvas does state push/pop), [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-state).

Comment: One more edit.. you'll need to increment your rotation angle. That's why the rotation isn't happening as an animation. It's happening, just not changing over time.